# Xamarin android, how to make navigation bar back button bigger and change color?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, rendering, navigationbar

I am using Xamarin forms, but I want to make navigation-bar back button only for android project. I simply want make it bigger and change color of it. What would be the best way to do it? Thank you for any answers or suggestions.

Comment: I would recommend looking up how to do this natively first. Then you can have an ideal of how you would do it in Xamarin.Forms or whether an API exists to do just this. You can look directly at the Xamarin.Forms source for any further insight: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Customize the Actionbar in the Android project.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rohit mentioned you will need a to customize the action bar inside the styles.xml which is inside the values folder inside the Resourses folder of your android project, James Montemagno did a blog post related to that when he introduce the FormsAppCompatActivity an example of a cuztom nav bar would be like this:

```
<style name="AppMainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#0063a4</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#003A63</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#86c447</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/AppBackgroundColor</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
</style>
```

And the blog post is here: https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/

In regards of navigation bar height it may involved more cuztomization and a custom view inside the Navigation Bar, here is an android example:

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar